# Does anyone have a handy visulization widget that I can use for a web project?

Tags: visualization

What I want is lots of nodes which can expand making a mind map.

I'd ideally like to expand and collapse nodes. I would like to be able to navigate by either dragging around the page, or by following expanded nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a colleague who needed that kind of functionalities to graph Maven dependencies between projects. He ended up using [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) to do the visualization. He just had to write an XML file conforming to the FreeMind format. I even think you can just use [OPML](http://www.opml.org/) as the file format and find a ready to use XSLT to transform it to the FreeMind format. Maybe FreeMind actually supports OPML directly (I havent used it for a long time).

Once you have your data in FreeMind, you can either export them, or use the [FreeMind applet](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/docs/Serving%20Freemind%20maps%20in%20a%20browser/freemind%20applet.html) to display an interactive MindMap on your website.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html).

Answer (score 1):

Suggest protovis, lovely javascript cross-platform visualisation library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a component that does what Visio can do, except that it can be displayed on a web page. Most likely you would have to create one from scratch, because mind mapping tools are always released as products per se and not customizable components. I suggest looking for a basic drawing/illustration component, and then putting your mind-mapping logic in it.